# Nano and ee not showing content of file just bottom line stacked up

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I'm having a problem with text editors in FreeBSD when opening a file I can't edit anything it only shows like on the picture below.
I'm using FreeNAS on FREEBSD 11.2[image]

Comment: Could it be that you don't have read permissions? Can you `cat /etc/rc.conf`?

Comment: Also, are you sure that this file has any content? `/etc/rc.conf` does not have to be present at all.

Comment: sorted out it is general bug on FreeNas

Comment: Could you post the solution then?

Comment: There is no solution yet they have to fix the bug in Freenas 11.2-RC1 for now I was forced to learn vi cause it is the only editor that works

Comment: Psst!  M. Piotrowski!  We know that the file exists and is readable, because there are its contents all on one line at the bottom of the screen.  Better requests for clarification would involve asking what the terminal emulator is and what the current `TERM` environment variable and line discipline settings are.